# Joomla Template Not able to see newly installed template

Tags: templates, joomla, joomla3.0

I am pretty new to joomla . I have a server http://www.newsnowis.com which was having an old installation and old data. I installed http://demo4.ltheme.com/joomla/lt-news/ template and set this template as default.

[image]

Now i open http://www.newsnowis.com/ what happens is it just redirects to http://www.newsnowis.com/english/ with a blank screen.

[image]

My expectation is it should open the template with sample data. Can anyone sugggest which configuration is wrong and missing? This server is running in godaddy would it be misconfiguration of Cpanel? Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

The more likely explanation for the blank screen when you set template is that the version of Joomla is too old for the template you have installed. Otherwise, you have installed a version of the template that isn't compatible with the version of Joomla you have installed.

Comment: Hi jegger thanks for your reply .. when I tested in my locale server it worked.. I have both local and godaddy server having same joomla version.. so I don't think this is an issue with version..

Comment: I understand. Have you tried using the default Joomla template (protostar)?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to see protostar I saw Isis default and that even not working

Comment: Probably the problem isn't related to the template. Try to see error.log in main directory (via ftp)

Comment: Even what I am not understanding is why it should open www.newnowis.com/English.  Where I can find the setting any idea?

Comment: It's a very strange issue if on server it wasn't happening. However, try to see error.log, try also to set error reporting at highest level. For the strange redirect, try to see htaccess, the redirect menu and control menu items